# how to pass argument to nested route in auto_route?

Tags: flutter, auto-route

I am using auto route and trying to implement persistent navigation bar with Nested Route.

my Routes:

```
List<AutoRoute> get routes => [
    AutoRoute(
      path: "/",
      initial: true,
      page: BaseRoute.page,
      children: [
        AutoRoute(
          path: "home_tab",
          page: HomeTabRoute.page,
          initial: true,
          children: [
            AutoRoute(path: "home_page", page: HomeRoute.page, initial: true),
          ],
        ),
        AutoRoute(
          path: "setting_tab",
          page: SettingTabRoute.page,
          children: [
            AutoRoute(
              path: "base_setting",
              page: SettingRoute.page,
              initial: true,
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
  ];
```

I render them in my tab page

setting_tab_page:

```
@RoutePage()
class SettingTabPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SettingTabPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const AutoRouter();
  }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is, say that the initial screen have an argument or a required parameter like this

setting_page

```
class SettingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final BuildContext context;
  const SettingPage({super.key, required this.context});
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

How would I pass an argument/parameter to that first screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation you could notice that:

> AutoRoute automatically detects and handles your page arguments for
> you, the generated route object will deliver all the arguments your
> page needs including path/query params.

But passing context is bad idea. may be you should pass params that you intent to retrieve from context.

More info [passing-arguments](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#passing-arguments)

If your page is nested, nothing is changed. AutoRoute still automatically detects and handles your page arguments for you.

```
AutoRouter.of(context).replace(
  const SettingRoute(..put your arguments),
);
```

as SettingRoute is initial in nested navigation you should replace/push/etc to the SettingRoute and not SettingTabPageRoute. and again - pass provider and not context then.

Comment: Thank you, but that document part is only for navigating to that specific pages. It doesn't say anything for nested navigation. I am passing context to get my provider, but realistically it could be an instance, an int, etc. And the problem would still be the same. There's no way for me to pass those arguments to that first page. Unless, you could show me an example relating to my case?

Comment: I had to place that code inside the `wrappedRoute` function with a post frame call back and passing PageRoute from the parent to direct where I want to navigate. but After that it works like a charm, thank you.